# Is Scanner Canon Pixma MG2450 supported in Linux?

Tags: linux, scanner, canon

The Cannon Pixma MG2450 printer has an integrated scanner that should work with a tool like Simple Scan (or Xsane, Skanlite).

I have the proper drivers (provided by Canon: `scangearmp-common` and `scangearmp-mg2400series`) and I was under the impression that with them the scanner worked in the past, but now Iţm not so sure... after trying and failing to make it work...

As seen [here](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON), the Cannon Pixma 2400 series look supported.

I cannot access the scan in Linux: I have tried to access it in Ubuntu and other *ubuntu-based systems like Linux Mint 17.2 KDE and elementary OS Freya.

[image]

The scanner cannot be faulty, because **it works in Windows** (I have multiple boot).

How could I investigate this farther?

**Can I be wrong that this scanner is supported and that it worked in the past?**

The printer works.

---

### But is this scanner really supported ?

---

`etc/sane.d/dll.d` contains only these two files:

[image]

Also:

```
      sudo sane-find-scanner
[sudo] password for cip: 

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports                                                                                                                          
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

Trying to start `skanlite` tool in terminal, I get:

```
 skanlite
Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address. 
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon
```

`etc/sane.d/ddl.conf` contains some lines starting with `cannon`, one `pixma`, none is commented out.

---

Edit after a first [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249967/32012):

The situation is a bit confusing so I try to follow the most simple part, the one about installing the scanner drivers first:

> if you install first the scanner, when you turn on the machine, after
>   installing the driver, mint installs the printer. Again you have to go
>   to Menu-Administration-Printers and eliminate the printer mint
>   installed for you. Then you can install the canon printer driver, this
>   time without interruptions

Using the debian packages instead of the deb files I get indeed a second entry in the printers list but there is no way I can make it disappear forever: any time I re-connect the printer, a second one is added. Removing it manually I have only the one installed by me but only until I reconnect the printer. Even so, the scanner doesn't work.

Anyway, the printer is not added automatically unless the Canon drives are installed!

Comment: The details at http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=186809 suggest it doesn't work with SANE, so worth trying those steps ?

Comment: do you have `libusb` and `libusb-dev` ? and what is the version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**.

Even if it doesn't work with Simple Scan on some systems, on others Simple Scan is working and/or sufficient.

---

### In Ubuntu-14.04-based systems

If the drivers are installed but tools like Simple Scan and Xsane do not work, there is a separate scanning GUI tool from Canon called **ScanGear** that is automatically installed when installing the driver packages (`scangearmp-common` and `scangearmp-mg2400series`), and that is specifically intended for use as scanning application with the Pixma integrated scanner.

**ScanGear** can be run with the command `scangearmp`.

[image]

As seen in comments under questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/128118/47206) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/685826/47206), there is also the idea of starting it within Gimp: **File/Create/ScanGear MP**

[image]

Also [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/325275/47206).

But Gimp is not needed in order for ScanGear to work, people mention Gimp because (as in my case) ScanGear doesn't create its own desktop file in `usr/share/applications`, is absent in the menu, and by default cannot be accessed in launchers like Synapse, Dash, Kickoff. To remedy this and get easy access to the application, add a `.desktop` launcher for ScanGear. With `gedit`text editor:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/scan.desktop
```

and pasting this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Graphics;Scanning;
Exec=scangearmp
Icon=scanner
Name=Scan
Type=Application
```

possibly making it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/scan.desktop
```

---

### **UPDATE on later systems**:

The above was tested in  ubuntu-14.04-based systems and in Manjaro 15.09 (with `scangearmp-common`).

As indicated in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320277/32012), in ubuntu-15.10 Simple Scan should work.

In ubuntu 16.04-based systems, Simple Scan is enough and the drivers for the scanner are not needed.

Testing in Manjaro 16.10, the same thing: `scangearmp-common` is not needed and Simple Scan is enough.

---

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

[This](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=186809) is how a chap by the name of Eduardo got it to work.

---

What it says is this:

> First, the scanner has no support by sane, so mint can't install it by
>   itself. There is no problem with the printer, gutenprint driver works
>   great. As soon as you connect and turn on the printer, mint installs
>   it, but there is no scanner. We need something else.
>
> Solution: download canon drivers from canon and install them. You have
>   to download - MG2400 series IJ Printer Driver Ver. 4.00 for Linux ,
>   debian package, and -MG2400 series ScanGear MP Ver. 2.20 for Linux
>   (debian Packagearchive). There are 2 manuals about these drivers
>   -ScanGear MP Ver. 2.20 for Linux (Operation guide) and -IJ Printer Driver Ver. 4.00 for Linux (Operation guide).
>
> Once you have downloaded and extracted the .tar.gz files, read the
>   manuals. Read them carefully and follow the instructions. The problem
>   I had was that mint installed the printer by itself, automatically,
>   and I didn't eliminate it, so I had the same printer with 2 different
>   configurations, one with the canon driver and other with gutenprint
>   driver. With this configuration just the gutenprint driver works,
>   there is no scanner even if you install canon scanner driver.
>
> When you install the canon printer driver with its installer
>   (./install.sh) first, before you can register the printer, mint has
>   installed it with its gutenprint driver, you only have the
>   notification. In the manuals, they say that "if a window that prompts
>   you to add a printer is automatically displayed when you connect the
>   machine, cancel the window by closing it.". Maybe you have the chance
>   with other distros, but mint doesn't ask. So you have to stop, go to
>   Menu-Administration-Printers and eliminate the printer mint installed
>   for you. Then you finish your canon printer driver installation. Turn
>   off the printer and install the scanner.
>
> The same story if you install first the scanner, when you turn on the
>   machine, after installing the driver, mint installs the printer. Again
>   you have to go to Menu-Administration-Printers and eliminate the
>   printer mint installed for you. Then you can install the canon printer
>   driver, this time without interruptions.

---

Sorry, for repeating the above solution, but it was answered while i was typing in my response. I hate it when this happens as it makes me appear stupid, but I blame it on old age.

Comment: Added edit in relation with the above answer.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the solution ... see my updated edit above.

Comment: cannot replicate the solution but i will award the bounty

Comment: Your answer did not provide a solution. i have awarded the bounty as it was expiring anyway (and for your good intentions). I have set a new bounty intended for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported. I have this printer connected to an Ubuntu 15.10 machine and it worked out of the box with `simple-scan`.

Comment: This seems dependent on the system/kernel. - I have updated my answer to point out that the problem seems limited to older systems like the ubuntu 14.04-based, and that in later systems the scanner drivers are not even needed, while Simple Scan is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have had to use Turboprint drivers for my new Canon TS8160. It works ok but needs paying for!
To get the scanner going I must use the terminal command  scangearmp2
All I need for that is a GUI and I'm happy.
OS is Mint 18.3