# How to come the GUI tool from scangearmp2

Tags: debian, scanner, canon

my print **Canon MAXIFY MB5150**

I have been downloading  **scangearmp2** from the canon [site](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/maxify_mb_series/maxify_mb5150.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit))

I installated it with,

```
cd ~/scangearmp2-3.40-1-deb/packages
sudo apt install scangearmp2_3.40-1_amd64.deb
```

and

```
cd ~/scangearmp2-3.40-1-deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

and it is recognize,

[image: image display how to come]

My question is, how can to have the graphical user interface GUI-tool from **scangearmp2** as [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257547) to show,

[image: how I'll to come]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, I asked in another Forum and people say to me that **scangearmp2** not to come the GUI tool. My Idee is to wait till Debian Buster have the **Sane** version **1.0.28**, now I have **1.0.27**, because **1.0.28** backed Maxify MB5100-Series.